# Java Regex Captures Too Much

Tags: java, regex

I have reduced my case to the simplest possible example and I still can't get it to work the same in Java and in Python.  Here is my Java code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String searchPattern = "gov.noaa.mgdc.mgg.dem:393";
    String regExToApply = ":(.+)$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExToApply);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchPattern);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Match is: \"" + matcher.group() + "\"");
        //Output: Match is: ":393"
    }


}
```

In Python, the regEx ":(.+)$" matches just the 393, which is what I want, but in Java, it matches :393.  I have tried specifically listing the : as a non-capturing group, "(?::)(.+)$" and I get the same result.  I've also noticed that removing the parentheses, ":.+$" seem to make no difference.

How do you capture just the 393 in the above string, in Java?  I also need a separate string to capture everything before the colon, not including the colon, as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just use the captured group defined in your regex rather than the whole matched expression returned by `matcher.group()`

```
System.out.println("Match is: \"" + matcher.group(1) + "\"");
                                                  ^
               captured group 1  -----------------|
```

Comment: Clarification: There is a difference between the text matching the *expression* vs. the text captured by a *capturing group*. A regex can have many capturing groups, which are defined using parenthesis. Your regex has one such capturing group. Capturing groups are numbered starting at 1, so the text of the first capturing group, which excludes the `:`, can be retrieved by calling `group(1)`. The `group()` method returns the whole text matched by the expression.

Comment: Reimeus: You'll get my up-vote too if you actually explain the problem. A solution without explanation is not that useful. You can copy my previous comment or write it in your own language, either way works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `matcher.group()` without any arguments is the same as calling `matcher.group(0)` which, according to the API documentation, returns the match for the entire pattern.

See API docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)

To get the group matched by a set of parentheses, you have to specify a number greater than 0. The one you're looking for is group number 1.

```
System.out.println("Match is: \"" + matcher.group(1) + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you were using `findall()`, weren't you?  That method is a bit peculiar.  If there are no capturing groups in the regex, it lists only complete matches, but if there *are* capturing groups, it lists only the groups.  The complete matches are still there, it just doesn't show them to you.

If you had used the `search()` method to obtain a `match` object, you would have found yourself with the same options you have in Java: `group()` or `group(0)` to retrieve the whole match (`:393`), or `group(1)` to get just the part that interests you (`393`).

Every language takes a different approach to regexes, and they all makes some surprising choices.  For example, in Java, `matches()` is a verb meaning "this regex describes the whole string", but in .NET, `Matches()` is a noun meaning "there may be one or more matches of this regex in the string; here's a list of all them".  Don't take anything for granted.